# Questions on the $n$-transitivity of $\operatorname{Diff}(M)$.

Tags: differential-geometry

Recently, I tried to understand how to proof the $n$-transitivity of $\operatorname{Diff}(M)$ acting on a smooth connected manifold $M$. I found a proof here [$n$-transitivity of $\operatorname{Diff}(M)$ acting on a smooth manifold $M$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2076639/n-transitivity-of-operatornamediffm-acting-on-a-smooth-manifold-m) and another article on [researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2697886_N-transitivity_of_certain_diffeomorphism_groups)
which follows the same ideas. However, I still have questions because of some details.

- **How do we prove that we actually can have disjoint embedded curves?** What are the hypothesis that we need to prove it? Because in one dimension it is obvious that it doesn't work. Both references take dim $\geq$ 2. But in two dimensions the closed unit disk is also a counterexample if we take points on the boundary (for example $(-1;0) \mapsto (1;0)$ and $(0;-1) \mapsto (0;1)$). So, do we have to add that $M$ is without boundary in our hypothesis? If we suppose those two, what's the proof of that? It doesn't seem elementary... (Or it is?)
- We took $(x_1, ... x_n)$ to be disctincts points, such as $(y_1, ..., y_n)$. But we need that both sets doesn't share common elements, isn't it? I think it is necessary for the proof, but maybe it is just a misunderstanding on my part of the defintion of $n$-transitivity.

Comment: 1) You can never move a boundary point to the interior via a diffeomorphism. So yes, they want you to consider the interior (a manifold without boundary). 2) Nope, you need not impose any disjointness condition between X and Y (but you do need to demand that each of the $x_i$ are pairwise distinct from one another; you must, independently, demand the same of $Y$.)

Comment: Yes, but what if all the points I consider are on the boundary?

Well, if I consider the $n$-transitivity definition from [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TransitiveGroupAction.html), we ask disjointness. Moreover, if those aren't disjoints, then the embedded curves will share common points...

Thanks for your answer.